# Proof involving a commutative ring and a denominator set

Tags: equivalence-relations, localization

I'm having a hard time with the following proof: Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $S$ $\subset$ $R$ a *denominator set*, that is, a subset closed under multiplication, containing $1$. We define a binary relation on the set $W$ $=$ $R$ $\times$ $S$ by $(a, s)$ $\sim$ $(b, t)$ whenever there exists $q$ $\in$ $S$ such that $atq$ $=$ $bsq$. Want to prove that this is an equivalence relation.

Please can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Reflexivity and symmetry are straightforward.

*Hint for transitivity:*
 By hypothese, there's a $q_1$ and a $q_2$ such that
$$(at)q_1=(bs)q_1,\qquad (bu)q_2=(ct)q_2.$$
Multiply the first equality by $uq_2$, the second by $sq_1$.

Comment: I proved the transitivity. How is reflexivity and symmetry shown?

Comment: Simply translating into formula; and straightforward checking